# Save PDF file to a user-defined default directory in iCloud Drive

Tags: swift, icloud, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm asking this question because I did not find any answer, and I'm starting to believe that it's not possible, due to security reasons. But who knows?

In my app, I simply let the user save a PDF file using `UIActivityViewController`. The user then chooses `Save to file`, then selects `iCloud Drive`.

Now, users ask me to be able to select a default location **once and for all**.
Is it possible? This location would of course be outside the app container, then I suppose iOS won't grant access unless the user selected it itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` you can ask for a directory, and you can save it in your app. This is explained in detail in [Providing Access to Directories](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_controllers/providing_access_to_directories). iOS 13 and later.

See also [What's New in File Management and Quick Look](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/719/) for sample code saving a directory URL and then reusing it to set the base directory for a subsequent call to `UIDocumentPickerViewController`

Comment: And how is this used together with UIActivityViewController?

Comment: `UIActivityViewController` is going to request a location each time a part of the Safe To Files action. The point about the security scoped URL gained from `UIDocumentPickerViewController ` is you can use it directly without user interaction. So you could  prompt to save at the default location, or ask for a new one.  Sorry if this doesn’t give you exactly what you are after.

Comment: Thank you @MichaelR, this is very valuable!